# How to write a query in SQL Server to find nearest values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Let's say that I have the following integer values in a table

```
32
11
15
123
55
54
23
43
44
44
56
23
```

OK, the list can go on; it doesn't matter. Now I want to query this table and I want to return a certain number of `closest records`. Let's say **I want to return 10 closest record matches to the numer 32.** Can I achieve this efficiently?

It is in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming the column is indexed the following should be reasonably efficient.

With two seeks of 10 rows and then a sort of the (up to) 20 returned.

```
WITH CTE
     AS ((SELECT TOP 10 *
          FROM   YourTable
          WHERE  YourCol > 32
          ORDER  BY YourCol ASC)
         UNION ALL
         (SELECT TOP 10 *
          FROM   YourTable
          WHERE  YourCol <= 32
          ORDER  BY YourCol DESC))
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM   CTE
ORDER  BY ABS(YourCol - 32) ASC
```

(i.e. potentially something like the below)

[image]

Or another possibility (that reduces the number of rows sorted to max 10)

```
WITH A
     AS (SELECT TOP 10 *,
                       YourCol - 32 AS Diff
         FROM   YourTable
         WHERE  YourCol > 32
         ORDER  BY Diff ASC, YourCol ASC),
     B
     AS (SELECT TOP 10 *,
                       32 - YourCol AS Diff
         FROM   YourTable
         WHERE  YourCol <= 32
         ORDER  BY YourCol DESC),
     AB
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   A
         UNION ALL
         SELECT *
         FROM   B)
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM   AB
ORDER  BY Diff ASC
```

[image]

NB: Execution plan above was for the simple table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YourTable](
    [YourCol] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [SomeIndex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

Technically, the Sort on the bottom branch shouldn't be needed either as that too is ordered by Diff, and it would be possible to merge the two ordered results. But I wasn't able to get that plan.

The query has `ORDER BY Diff ASC, YourCol ASC` and not just `ORDER  BY YourCol ASC`, because that was what ended up working to get rid of the Sort in the top branch of the plan. I needed to add the secondary column in (even though it won't ever change the result as `YourCol` will be the same for all values with the same Diff) so it would go through the merge join (concatenation) without adding a Sort.

SQL Server seems able to infer that an index on X seeked in ascending order will deliver rows ordered by X + Y and no sort is necessary. But it is not able to infer that travelling the index in descending order will deliver rows in the same order as Y-X (or even just unary minus X). Both branches of the plan use an index to avoid a sort but the `TOP 10` in the bottom branch are then sorted by `Diff` (even though they are already in that order) to get them in the desired order for the merge.

For other queries/table definitions it may be trickier or not possible to get the merge plan with just a sort of one branch - as it relies on finding an ordering expression that SQL Server:

1. Accepts that the index seek will supply the specified order so no sort is needed *before* the top.
2. Is happy to use in the merge operation so requires no sort after the `TOP`

Answer (score 3):

I am bit puzzled and surprised that we have to do Union in this case. Following is simple and more efficient

```
SELECT TOP (@top) *
FROM @YourTable
ORDER BY ABS(YourCol-@x)
```

Following is the complete code and execution plan comparing the both queries

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (YourCol INT)
INSERT @YourTable (YourCol)
VALUES  (32),(11),(15),(123),(55),(54),(23),(43),(44),(44),(56),(23)

DECLARE @x INT = 100, @top INT = 5

--SELECT TOP 100 * FROM @YourTable
SELECT TOP (@top) *
FROM @YourTable
ORDER BY ABS(YourCol-@x)

;WITH CTE
     AS ((SELECT TOP 10 *
          FROM   @YourTable
          WHERE  YourCol > 32
          ORDER  BY YourCol ASC)
         UNION ALL
         (SELECT TOP 10 *
          FROM   @YourTable
          WHERE  YourCol <= 32
          ORDER  BY YourCol DESC))
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM   CTE
ORDER  BY ABS(YourCol - 32) ASC
```

[image: Execution plan comparison]

Comment: Your solution would only be faster if the column is **not** indexed. Otherwise the solution with union is optimal. (Take a look at the diagrams: you have Table Scan instead of Index Seek.)

Comment: But that is also true for other solution i.e. other solution is also using table scan. This is what I wanted to point out.

Answer (score -3):

Refinement of Martin's second suggestion:

```
WITH AB
     AS (SELECT *, ABS(32 - YourCol) AS Offset
         FROM   YourTable),
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM   AB
ORDER  BY Offset ASC
```

Comment: It may be a bit simpler code but it's going to be much less efficient. We could even use `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM   YourTable ORDER  BY ABS(YourCol - 32) ;` Even more simple. Not efficient either.